# Integrate Keycloak with GKE cluster for Single Sign-On (SSO) and "invalid redirect URI" error

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, single-sign-on, keycloak, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to integrate Keycloak with my GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) cluster to enable Single Sign-On (SSO) so developers can access their namespace easily. However, I'm encountering an "invalid redirect URI" error and I'm unsure how to fix it. Here are the details of my setup:

I deploy a GKE cluster with terraform.
I have deployed Keycloak with helm in the same cluster.
I have configured Keycloak to use an external OAuth2 identity provider for SSO.
I have set up the necessary client settings and redirect URIs which is the ip of the gke cluster in Keycloak.

I followed the medium blog to do so:

https://medium.com/elmo-software/kubernetes-authenticating-to-your-cluster-using-keycloak-eba81710f49b

when I use kubelogin on another computer I will be granted access to gke cluster but it gives me the error "invalid redirect URI"

Comment: please share code and full error